# What is defaultValue type for createContext which value's type is React.ProviderProps<unknown>.value: unknown?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types, react-context

I'm implementing theme toggler to my website with createContext and I run into this error:

> 'Expected 1 arguments, but got 0.ts(2554)
> An argument for 'defaultValue' was not provided.'

I know that I need to pass default value to `const ThemeUpdateContext = React.createContext()`, but I'm using this createContext for a function, that doesn't return anything. What is the best way to define defaultValue here?

Here is my code:

```
import React, { useState, useContext, ReactNode } from 'react'

const ThemeContext = React.createContext(true)
const ThemeUpdateContext = React.createContext()

export const useTheme = () => {
  const context = useContext(ThemeContext)
  if (context === undefined) {
    throw Error('ThemeContext must be within ThemeProvider')
  }
  return context
}

export const useUpdateTheme = () => {
  const context = useContext(ThemeUpdateContext)
  if (context === undefined) {
    throw Error('ThemeUpdateContext must be within ThemeProvider')
  }
  return context
}

const ThemeProvider = ({ children }: { children: ReactNode }) => {
  const [darkTheme, setDarkTheme] = useState(true)

  const toggleTheme = () => {
    setDarkTheme((prev) => !prev)
  }

  return (
    <ThemeContext.Provider value={darkTheme}>
      <ThemeUpdateContext.Provider value={toggleTheme}>
        {children}
      </ThemeUpdateContext.Provider>
    </ThemeContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, you are not passing `defaultValue` as function in ThemeUpdateContext.

To fix this error, you can try this:

```
const ThemeUpdateContext = React.createContext(() => {});
```

Alternatively, you can use only one `Context`.

For example:

```
import React, { useState, useContext, ReactNode } from "react";

type ThemeContextType = {
  theme: boolean;
  toggleTheme: () => void;
};

const ThemeContext = React.createContext<ThemeContextType>({
  theme: true,
  toggleTheme: () => {},
});

export const useTheme = () => {
  const { theme } = useContext(ThemeContext);
  return theme;
};

export const useUpdateTheme = () => {
  const { toggleTheme } = useContext(ThemeContext);
  return toggleTheme;
};

export const ThemeProvider = ({ children }: { children: ReactNode }) => {
  const [darkTheme, setDarkTheme] = useState(true);

  const toggleTheme = () => {
    setDarkTheme((prev) => !prev);
  };

  return (
    <ThemeContext.Provider value={{ theme: darkTheme, toggleTheme }}>
      {children}
    </ThemeContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thank you, that does look neater. Now it's eslint that doesn't like empty function ()=> {},  but that's not that hard to solve)